# How to build a service for Google Calendar API using a service account?

Tags: python, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am using OAuth2.0 with a Google Service Account to try and manage a calendar. I have the sample code in Python provided below:

```
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials
from httplib2 import Http
from apiclient.discovery import build

client_email = "<service_account_client_email>"
with open("key.p12") as f:
    priv_key = f.read()

cred = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(client_email, priv_key, "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar", sub="<user_to_impersonate>")
http_auth = cred.authorize(Http())

service = build(serviceName='calendar', version='v3', http=http_auth)
```

So far, I get the exception "Requested client not authorized" when running the code.

I have followed the steps in Google's documentation:

1. Delegate domain-wide authority to your service account (I created the service account, but I am not an administrator for the domain. However, a user who is an administrator performed this step).
2. Verified that the scope is set to use the calendar, and the API is enabled in developer console.
3. Shared the  calendar with the service account (though the option to manage the calendar is unavailable).

What steps am I missing? Is my scope incorrect just for building the service?

Comment: Did you add the scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar in your administrator console?

Comment: @SGC Are you referring to the scope? The administrator console shows the service account ClientID under "ClientName", and it shows "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar" under scope.